# Why do I have a document.getElementById is Null?

Tags: javascript, dom, null

While attempting to create a script for a small game for a class, I have been having problems geting the script itself to load.  I keeping getting information back saying type error: document.getElementById is Null.  I am very new to Javascript and coding in general so I am both confused as to what it means and how to fix it.  The webpage looks right, but there is no fuction at all.  I will leave you the code for all of it.  The problem is with the Javascript portion thank you for your help.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("userInput").value = "";

  document.getElementById("img1").onmouseover = function(evt) {
    swapImageClass("img1", 2, "onmouseover");
  } // img1 onmouseover event

  document.getElementById("img2").onmouseover = function(evt) {
    swapImageClass("img2", 2, "onmouseover");
  } // img2 onmouseover event

  document.getElementById("img3").onmouseover = function(evt) {
    seapImageClass("img3", 2, "onmouseover");
  } // img3 onmouseover event

  document.getElementById("img1").onmouseout = function(evt) {
    swapImageClass("img1", 1, "onmouseout");
  } // img1 onmouseout event

  document.getElementById("img2").onmouseout = function(evt) {
    swapImageClass("img2", 1, "onmouseout");
  } // img2 onmouseout event

  document.getElementById("img3").onmouseout = function(evt) {
    swapImageClass("img3", 1, "onmouseout");
  } // img3 onmouseout event

  document.getElementById("img3").onclick = function(evt) {
    swapImageClass("img3", 3, "onclick");
  } // img3 onclick event

  document.getElementById("userInput").onblur = function(evt) {
    addEventOutputTracking("onblur", "userInput", "current value of userinput field: \"" + document.getElementById("userInput").value + "\"");
  } // userInput onblur event

  document.getElementById("processUserText").onclick = function(evt) {
    addEventOutputTracking("onclick", "processUserText", "processed value of userinput field: \"" + document.getElementById("userInput").value + "\"");
  } // userInput onclick event

  document.getElementById("clearOutput").onclick = function(evt) {
    resetOutput();
  } // clearOutput onclick event

} // end window.onload

function swapImageClass(imageID, imageState, eventName) {
  var outputText = "Event action on element ID " + imageID;
  addEventOutputTracking(eventName, outoutText, "");

  document.getElementById(imageID).className = "img" + imageState;
} // end function swapImageClass

function addEventOutputTracking(eventName, outputText, extraText) {
  var node; // for element to add child element later
  var pChildNode = document.createElement("p"); // new element that will be child of node

  // new document parts created, so add them to document
  node = document.getElementById("eventOutput"); // existing div we are adding to
  node.appendChild(pChildNode); // adding p element as child of div
  pChildNode.appendChild(document.createTextNode("User Event: " + eventName + " - " + outputText + " " + extraText)); // adding text to new p element
} // end function addEventOutputTracking

function resetOutput() {
  var node = document.getElementById("eventOutput");
  while (node.firstChild)
    node.removeChild(node.firstChild);

  node.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Recently Cleared - Space is reserved for event output information"));
} // end function resetOutput
```

```css
.img1 {
  margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  border: 3px solid blue;
}

.img2 {
  margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  border: 3px dashed green;
}

.img3 {
  margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  border: 3px dotted red;
}

span {
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  background-color: #00FFFF;
}

#eventOutput {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 620px;
  padding: 10px;
  front-size: small;
  color: blue;
  background-color: #FFFF99
}

#firstP {
  front-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http:www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
  <title>Lesson 8 \code Sample - DOM</title>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="lesson-8.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lesson-8.css">

</head>

<body>
  <p>
    <img class="img1" id="img1" src="one.gif" />
    <img class="img1" id="img2" src="two.gif" />
    <img class="img1" id="img3" src="three.gif" />
    <p>

      <p>
        <input id="userinput" type="text" size="50" /><br /> User Input Text
      </p>

      <p>
        <span id="processUserText">Process Input</span>
        <span id="clearOutput">Reset Output</span>
      </p>

      <div id="eventOutput">
        <p id="firstP">This space is reserved for event output information</p>
      </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're so so so close! A very small typo through your whole code off.

In your javascript, you have `document.getElementById("userInput")`. However, in your html, the id is actually `userinput`. Notice the difference? **HTML ids are case sensitive**

Simply change the id in your html to `userInput`

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("userInput").value = "";

  document.getElementById("img1").onmouseover = function(evt) {
    swapImageClass("img1", 2, "onmouseover");
  } // img1 onmouseover event

  document.getElementById("img2").onmouseover = function(evt) {
    swapImageClass("img2", 2, "onmouseover");
  } // img2 onmouseover event

  document.getElementById("img3").onmouseover = function(evt) {
    seapImageClass("img3", 2, "onmouseover");
  } // img3 onmouseover event

  document.getElementById("img1").onmouseout = function(evt) {
    swapImageClass("img1", 1, "onmouseout");
  } // img1 onmouseout event

  document.getElementById("img2").onmouseout = function(evt) {
    swapImageClass("img2", 1, "onmouseout");
  } // img2 onmouseout event

  document.getElementById("img3").onmouseout = function(evt) {
    swapImageClass("img3", 1, "onmouseout");
  } // img3 onmouseout event

  document.getElementById("img3").onclick = function(evt) {
    swapImageClass("img3", 3, "onclick");
  } // img3 onclick event

  document.getElementById("userInput").onblur = function(evt) {
    addEventOutputTracking("onblur", "userInput", "current value of userinput field: \"" + document.getElementById("userInput").value + "\"");
  } // userInput onblur event

  document.getElementById("processUserText").onclick = function(evt) {
    addEventOutputTracking("onclick", "processUserText", "processed value of userinput field: \"" + document.getElementById("userInput").value + "\"");
  } // userInput onclick event

  document.getElementById("clearOutput").onclick = function(evt) {
    resetOutput();
  } // clearOutput onclick event

} // end window.onload

function swapImageClass(imageID, imageState, eventName) {
  var outputText = "Event action on element ID " + imageID;
  addEventOutputTracking(eventName, outoutText, "");

  document.getElementById(imageID).className = "img" + imageState;
} // end function swapImageClass

function addEventOutputTracking(eventName, outputText, extraText) {
  var node; // for element to add child element later
  var pChildNode = document.createElement("p"); // new element that will be child of node

  // new document parts created, so add them to document
  node = document.getElementById("eventOutput"); // existing div we are adding to
  node.appendChild(pChildNode); // adding p element as child of div
  pChildNode.appendChild(document.createTextNode("User Event: " + eventName + " - " + outputText + " " + extraText)); // adding text to new p element
} // end function addEventOutputTracking

function resetOutput() {
  var node = document.getElementById("eventOutput");
  while (node.firstChild)
    node.removeChild(node.firstChild);

  node.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Recently Cleared - Space is reserved for event output information"));
} // end function resetOutput
```

```css
.img1 {
  margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  border: 3px solid blue;
}

.img2 {
  margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  border: 3px dashed green;
}

.img3 {
  margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  border: 3px dotted red;
}

span {
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  background-color: #00FFFF;
}

#eventOutput {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 620px;
  padding: 10px;
  front-size: small;
  color: blue;
  background-color: #FFFF99
}

#firstP {
  front-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http:www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
  <title>Lesson 8 \code Sample - DOM</title>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="lesson-8.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lesson-8.css">

</head>

<body>
  <p>
    <img class="img1" id="img1" src="one.gif" />
    <img class="img1" id="img2" src="two.gif" />
    <img class="img1" id="img3" src="three.gif" />
    <p>

      <p>
        <input id="userInput" type="text" size="50" /><br /> User Input Text
      </p>

      <p>
        <span id="processUserText">Process Input</span>
        <span id="clearOutput">Reset Output</span>
      </p>

      <div id="eventOutput">
        <p id="firstP">This space is reserved for event output information</p>
      </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Technically, it's that HTML ids and `.getElementById()` are case sensitive, as opposed to, say, tag names, which are not, so `.getElementsByTagName()` can use `"DIV"` or `"div"`.

Comment: @ziggywiggy you're right. That completely slipped my mind. Fixing it right now

Comment: Oh shoot!  Thankl you so much this is very helpful!

Comment: Aniket G and ziggy wiggy you two have been a big help.  Now just for fun, how would I switch the numbers out for different pictures pn both onmouseout and onmouseclick?

Comment: @DanielMacias 2 things. 1: Accept the answer if it worked for you. And 2: That's a separate question that you need to post. I can answer that for you but you need to post a separate question for that